# Dynamically generated form elements missing from POST data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The PHP page loads with a form, when the user clicks a '+' button, it adds form elements including class name and timing of class etc. with JQUERY.

When the form is submitted, these dynamically generated elements are missing from  the $_POST array. As a result the data entry mechanism fails.

Tried moving the submit code from a different file to the same file to rule out the variables being dropped.

Checked the network tab in the DevTools console for the post data, the elements created in PHP are the only post variables available.

What am I missing ?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    countCourses++;
    window.console && console.log("Adding course -"+countCourses);

        $('#tbl').append("<tr id='"+countCourses+"'><td><input type='text' 
    id='course"+countCourses+"' value='' class='course_name'></td> </td><td> 
   <select id='schedule"+countCourses+"' class='Schedule' ></select></td><td>  
   <input type='text' id='CRN"+countCourses+"' class='CRN' value='' 
    maxlength='5'></td><td><input type='text' id='credit"+countCourses+"' 
   class='credit' value='' ></td></tr>");
    };





<form method="POST">
   <p>
    <label for='name'>Name: </label>
    <input type="textbox" name="name" id="name" <?php echo "value = '{$user['FirstName']} {$user['LastName']}' readonly"; ?>  >
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for='pantherid'>Panther ID: </label>
    <input type="textbox" name="pantherid" id="pantherid" <?php echo "value = '{$user['PantherID']}' readonly"; ?>  >
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for='term'>Term: </label>
    <?php echo $term_widget; ?>
  </p>
  <p>
    Course: <input type="submit" id="add_course" value="+">
    <p>
      <div id="course_fields">
        <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id="tbl_course">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Course</th>
              <th>Schedule</th>
              <th>CRN</th> 
              <th>Credits</th>                      
              <tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id='tbl'>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </p>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel">
      </p>

    </form>
```

Comment: Must have `name` on form controls in order for them to submit otherwise they are ignored

Comment: could you elaborate with an example ?

Comment: Same way you have `name` on the existing inputs like `name="pantherid"`

Comment: Thank you !!!! Worked like a charm !

Comment: You have to post key/value pairs....and the control `name` is the *key*